# How do I add an indicator to my .menu-item if it contains a .sub-menu?

Tags: css, navigation

If your common with the code that wp_nav_menu function generates. You should know what im asking for.

I need to add an indicator like a plus sign or an arrow to indicate that this menu-item has a sub-menu. I cant find a class or id that would allow me to do that.

Im guessing ill need a plugin for this? BUT I need some opinion first.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with JS I'm afraid. It's the quickest simplest form. Using jQuery I have this snippet.

```
jQuery(function($){
   $('.menu li:has(".sub-menu")').addClass('has-sub-menu');
});
```

Then you can use CSS to do what you need :)

Comment: Thanks. 

I actually made a small plugin that adds a .sub-menu, .menu-item-last, and .menu-item-last to the menu mark up.